# select value which is equal to a variable in php

Tags: php, sql, variables

```
SELECT clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName, apointments.ApointmentDate, apointments.ApointmentTime from clients inner join Apointments on clients.ApointmentRef=Apointments.ApointmentRef where clients.apointmentref=3
```

this is basically the statement i am using but instead of 3, let the user input and number and return the results this is what i have tried:

the user enters a value:

```
<input id="apointment" name="apointment">

function _(x){
            return document.getElementById(x);
        }
function submitdata(){
        apointment = _("apointment").value;
        _("multiphase").method = "post";
        _("multiphase").action = "submitdata.php";
        _("multiphase").submit();
        _("phase8").style.display="none";
        _("phase9").style.display="none";
        _("phase10").style.display="none";
        _("phase11").style.display="none";
        _("phase12").style.display="none";
        _("finalphase").style.display="block";
    }
```

and my code in the submitdata.php is as follows:

```
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$HomePhone = $_POST['HomePhone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
$NaturalHairColour = $_POST['NaturalHairColour'];
$OtherDetails = $_POST['OtherDetails'];
$ApointmentRef = $_POST['Apointment'];
$apointment = $GET['apointment'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (ApointmentRef, FirstName, lastname, address, PhoneNumber, HomePhone, email, Comments, NaturalHairColour, OtherDetails)
VALUES ('$ApointmentRef','$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Address', '$PhoneNumber', '$HomePhone', '$email', '$Comments', '$NaturalHairColour', '$OtherDetails')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    $sql2= "SELECT clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName, apointments.ApointmentDate, apointments.ApointmentTime from clients where clients.apointmentRef='$apointment' inner join Apointments on clients.ApointmentRef=Apointments.ApointmentRef whereclients.apointmentref";
    $result = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "First Name: " . $row["FirstName"]."Last Name: " .  $row["LastName"]." Apointment Date: " . $row["ApointmentDate"]. " Appointment Time: " . $row["ApointmentTime"]. "<br>";
  }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
}

} else {
echo "Error: Apointment Unavailable, Please select another Slot" ;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What's the question and what errors are you getting? Doesn't look like you are checking for errors.

Comment: I didn't read the question well, I just seen a mistake: put a `space` after `where` clause at `whereclients.apointmentref";`

Comment: @Farhęg That wouldn't work; there shouldn't be more than one `where` in a query to start with, so it's probably their table name. But you are 50% right. However, it should be an `AND` or an `OR` or as a sub-query.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, of course there shouldn't be 2 `where`'s per one `select`, as I told I didn't notice and read well, however I think this question is offtopic

Comment: Rachel what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I think using mysql_* functions for db will not be supported for long.  I strongly suggest you need to use PDO functions for your database queries

Comment: @user2411276 *"I think using mysql_* functions for db will not be supported for long."* - OP isn't using `mysql_`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  thanks. yes missed it.  but I wanted to suggest Rachel to use parameterized queries.

Comment: By the way this `$GET` there's a syntax error there.

Comment: the problem i am facing is i'm getting back 0 results when i should be getting back data from the clients and appointments table